# Multiple identifiers for a category into one variable in R

Tags: r, data-cleaning, code-organization

I have survey data that I have read into my R file. How do I define variables for multiple data points that are meant to be in the same category?
I.e. for the Gender column I have: "M", "male", "Male", "Guy", etc. I want to have Male= "M", "male", "Male", "Guy".
Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: Please provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the column is `character` class, we can use `%in%` to create a logical index to replace these values with a new one

```
df1$Col[df1$Col %in% c("M", "male", "Guy")] <- "Male"
```